# Batch Script Parsing Dir Command

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, scripting, dir

Hello newbie looking for some help. I am trying to write a script to search all files and folders in my drive which have a certain identifier. For example "ID -"

I was using the following to get files and directories listed in a log file:

```
dir ID * /A:-D-H /B /S >> C:\FileCatalogue.log 2>> C:\FileCatalogue.log
dir ID * /A:D-H /T:C /S >> C:\DirCatalogue.log 2>> C:\DirCatalogue.log
```

However I want the output to be in 3 tabbed columns:

FILE {tab} DIR {tab} ID

ID123 - YYYY - myfile.txt  {tab}   C:/tmp/tmp  {tab}    ID123 - YYYY

etc..

etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Victor

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=-" %%a in ('dir /a-d/b ID*') do echo %%a-%%b  %cd%  %%a
```

Comment: you forgot the `/s` and the YYYY at the end - (well, the `YYYY` is easy with `tokens=1,2*`)

Comment: @Stephan I got nothing :) what is `/s`  please?

Comment: in your answer it is `dir /a-d/b ID*`, user2623499 requested a `dir /a:-D-H /B /S`.  /s stands for "including sub-dirs" - but I'm *very* sure, you know that ;)

Comment: What do you think, would an additional for-loop help? :)

Comment: if we only could be sure, there is no `-`in the path... Then your code would work fine and smoth (even with the addition of `/s`). What do you think of `forfiles`?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a:-d-h /b /s /t:c ID123*') do for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=-" %%B in ("%%~nxA") do echo(%%~nxA    %%~dpA  %%B-%%C
```

Output

```
ID123 - YYYY - myfile.txt   C:\Users\User\Desktop\  ID123 - YYYY
```